# How do I cure an otool execution failure?

Tags: unix, homebrew, otool

I get the following error when attempting to install something via brew:

```
$~:brew install carthage
Error: Failure while executing: /usr/bin/otool -L /usr/bin/install_name_tool
$~:
```

How do I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** path included 'xcode.app'; but am using '**xcode-beta**.app'.
**Solution:** renamed 'xcode-beta.app' to '**xcode**.app'.